# How can I configure a server with multiple IP addresses *without* using virtualization?

Tags: virtualization, web-server, ipv6, nic, sr-iov

If I want to set up multiple IPv6 addresses on a web server, can I do this **without** using virtualization/VMs?

How would I do this on modern Linux kernels (5.x) or Windows Server 2016/2019?

Relatedly, is it possible to use the virtualization features of a NIC without using virtualization on the OS or CPU side? I know that [it's possible](https://medium.com/@tukai.anirban/sr-iov-in-docker-containers-f13fdb297da0) to use the SR-IOV feature on NICs with containers, not just VMs. Could I use SR-IOV or similar without using containers or VMs, just dishing out the NIC to different bare metal web server app instances?

Thanks.

Comment: Just add secondary IPs that are routed to your machine/localnet

Comment: On Linux, one NIC can have multiple IP addresses.  A single web-server can listen on multiple ports and IP addresses.  A single or multiple "Listen" directives will handle those.

Comment: As others have said, you can simply do this at the OS level. It's called `multihoming`, and it can be done just by adding additional IPs to the NIC.

Comment: @ulfy how is a secondary IPs `multihoming` ? 
multihoming is 2+ gateways/routes, generally two or more upstream systems and BGP/Routing protocols involved to manipulate routing tables for best/shortest paths

Comment: @JacobEvans , you're right - I mixed up the terms in my head while rapid firing a comment.  Multihoming/dual-homing/aliasing flashed through my mind. The correct term for this would be IP aliasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Additional IPs

Note that many application servers listen on ALL IPs (IPv4 and IPv6); you may need to tell your applications to bind specific IPs to avoid port conflicts (like Nginx or IIS)

**Windows**
[image]

**Linux**

Read the Docs at [Netplan](https://netplan.io/examples)

create a file at /etc/netplan/config.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
         - "2001:db8::10/64"
         - "2001:db8::11/64"
         - "2001:db8::12/64"
```

Comment: Thanks. Are there any hitches with using secondary IPs? Are there other solutions or is using secondary IPs the only one?

Comment: For some reason the Netplan docs don't mention primary/secondary IPs, just IPs.

Comment: Modern network stacks can do one interface with many IP addresses. You are inferring too much into the word "secondary" IPs, which is not a standard term, nor does it mean they are inferior. Perhaps think of them as "additional" IP addresses, hidden in advanced TCP/IP on Windows just because of an unfortunate UI.

Comment: @LearningFast make sure whatever application you are using is only bound to one IP if you are using this to separate access to your applications.  Generally SNI is sufficient for HTTPS separation but I'm not aware of what services you are exposing requiring the use of multiple IP Addresses.