# Can we have multiple IP addresses with different Net IDs on an interface?

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet, interface

Can we have multiple IP addresses with different Net IDs on an interface? Like a Network Card? For example setting up 192.168.1.2 and 18.170.2.5 on the same network card. If yes, where do we use this method?

Comment: windows? linux? how are you planning to handle routing? what purpose? what are you trying to solve?

Comment: @JacobEvans This is a homework question. it says that if its possible to do so, explain how to do it in windows

Comment: Then you're in the wrong SE site. ServerFault is about IT in a business environment, not about homework questions.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1024766/how-can-i-configure-a-server-with-multiple-ip-addresses-without-using-virtuali/1024768#1024768

Answer (score 2):

> Can we have multiple IP addresses with different Net IDs on an
> interface?

Yes, you can. There might be many reasons for doing this. Mutli-homing a host with a single NIC connected to the same physical network as hosts in two different layer 3 networks is one example.

Comment: Thanks, how can I set this method up on Windows?